# Changing `\cftsecpresnum` only for appendices?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I would like for my table of contents to display the word "Appendix" before the section number for items that are in the appendix.  Unfortunately, the command that I used to get the word "Chapter" in before the chapter number:

```
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{7.5em}
\let\oldcftchappresnum\cftchappresnum
\renewcommand*{\cftchappresnum}{CHAPTER \oldcftchappresnum}
```

seems to actually "execute" when I call `\tableofcontents`, and so is "all or nothing" in some sense.  Is there a way to have the term "Appendix" appear before the section number in my toc?

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{7.5em}
\let\oldcftchappresnum\cftchappresnum
\renewcommand*{\cftchappresnum}{CHAPTER \oldcftchappresnum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{foo}

\section{bar}

\appendix

\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{7.5em}
\let\oldcftsecpresnum\cftsecpresnum
\renewcommand*{\cftsecpresnum}{APPENDIX \oldcftsecpresnum}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\rm{APPENDIX}}

\section{appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Expected behavior is that the line that says:

> A    appendix ... 3

Should say

> APPENDIX A     appendix ... 3

Comment: Could you please post a small compilable code of what you've tried?

Comment: @Bernard as you wish!

Comment: Off-topic: `\rm` is a switch and thus doesn't take an argument

Comment: @Mico Actually, `\rm` should ***never*** be used. The OP wants `\normalfont` (declaration).

Comment: @egreg - I was very much hoping for a one-two punch of this type. ;-) With some luck, the OP, and maybe some other readers of this posting, will stop using `\rm` in their LaTeX documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to export the changes to the `.toc` file.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{7.5em}
\renewcommand*{\cftchappresnum}{CHAPTER }

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{foo}

\section{bar}

\appendix

\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{7.5em}%
  \protect\renewcommand*{\protect\cftsecpresnum}{APPENDIX }%
}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalfont APPENDIX}

\section{appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]